# Can you query an array? Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

Maybe a silly question here, but I am working on an app where we need to calculate some basic demographic stats.  I want to make a trip to the data base once and then try and query that array of Eloquent models. Right now I am getting an array using the query, and then looping through it to count some stats.

i.e.

```
$people = Person::all();
$total = count($people);
$count = 0;
foreach($people as $person)
    if($person->age > 60) {
        count++;
    }
}
$percent = $count/$total;
```

Which works but we have to do this for hundreds of data points.

Can I do something like this?

i.e.

```
$people = Person::all();
$total = count($people);
$count = $people->where('age', '>=', '60')->count();
$percent = $count/$total;
```

My thought is that the latter will be more efficient (if possible) because it only makes one trip to the database and doing the aggregate stuff on server side? Or would it be better to make multiple queries and get the  database to do all the aggregate stuff?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, Eloquent has an aggregate `count` method, try this:

```
$total = Person::count();
$count = Person::where('age', '>=', '60')->count();
$percent = $count/$total;
```

Comment: I like this approach, but was still making many trips to DB right? I have been asking around the office and seems ultimate solution is creating a stored procedure to do all the aggregation and call that from  laravel, so only make one trip with only the data you need.

Comment: I think you're right @MattCatellier, many queries to DB can make the process slow

Comment: Thanks Jose! Think the stored procedure will require a little more work, but something that is good to know. Ill try and post my solution when I find it

Answer (score 2):

You want Collections.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections

Collections in Laravel are handy Array wrappers that provide additional logic that is very similar to the ODB structure. In fact, when you get Eloquent results, you get a special Database collections.

https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html
https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html

You can use a variety of logic on both of these object types that are basically identical to Builders for Eloquent DB queries.

Comment: this seems to be best solution to the general question I asked, filtering arrays in Laravel.  I marked jose' up because it was more suited towards my situation.  This is something I will look into if this comes up again.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more efficient to query the database once, and then [filter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-filter) the resulting collection:

```
$people = Person::all();
$total = count($people);
$peopleOver60 = $people->filter(function($item) {
    return $item->age >= 60;
});

$percent = count($peopleOver60) / $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes is great for performance 
and You can change your code  like that :$people to Person::

```
$people = Person::all();
$total = count($people);
$count = Person::where('age', '>=', '60')->count();
$percent = $count/$total;
```

Answer (score -2):

Your database optimized for searching queries but PHP isn't. You should use your "where" queries in DB. But if you want it anyway you can check this library : 
https://phplinq.codeplex.com/